# Sox: Convert a .wav file with required properties in a single command

Tags: command, conversion, sox

I have a `test.wav` file. 
I need to use this file to process an application, with following properties:

1. monochannel
2. 16 kHz sample rate
3. 16-bit

Now, I'm using the following commands to attain these properties:

```
sox disturbence.wav -r 16000 disturbence_16000.wav
sox disturbence_16000.wav -c 1 disturbence_1600_mono.wav
sox disturbence_1600_mono.wav -s -b 16 disturbence_1600_mono_16bit.wav
```

Here to get a single file,
three steps are involved and two temporary files are created. 
It is a time-consuming process.

I thought of writing a script to do these process but I'm keeping this is a last option.

In single command, can I convert a `.wav` file to the required format?

Comment: What should the `-s`-option do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`sox disturbence.wav -r 16000 -c 1 -b 16 disturbence_16000_mono_16bit.wav`

gives within one command

- Sample rate of 16 kHz (`-r 16000`),
- one channel (mono) (`-c 1`),
- 16 bits bit depth (`-b 16`).

Answer (score 1):

one-liner for all `.wav` files in the directory:

```
for file in *.wav; do sox $file -r 16000 -c 1 -b 16 "$(basename $file .wav)_16000_mono_16bit.wav" -V; done
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).